# Qt5 Stacked Widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstackedwidget

I created a *Qt* stacked widget that has 2 pages. The first page (`stackedWidgetPage1`) has 1 label and 1 button. The second page (`stackedWidgetPage2`) has 1 label. When I press the button the below code runs. The code is supposed to change the currently visible page from  page 1 to page2. But, when the code runs, the label gets "cut" in half. The expected result is that page 1 would be completely hidden and page 2 would be completely visible.

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->stackedWidgetPage1->hide();
    ui->stackedWidgetPage2->show();
}
```

page1[image: page1]

page2[image: page2]

program started[image: program started]

after I clicked the button[image: after i clicked the button]

Comment: read [ask] and improve your question

Comment: I'm sorry, but I won't click 6 clicks to answer a question.

Comment: Please do not post images of your code. Other than that, I think this is a good question. It seems you are new to SO, so let me say something else. Don't be discouraged by the downvotes. That happens to almost every question. I think the initial downvotes are artificially created by SO to scare people into improving their question. Also, don't worry about your English. English is a stupidly hard and flat out dumb language. If anything, I envy you for having English not be your primary language.

Comment: More importantly, Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and Ask a question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: All the meta aside, have you tried `ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(int)` instead of hiding and showing pages?

Comment: @Aditya Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Answer: ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(int) It Worked!

Comment: Please don't forget to mark this as the correct answer